# Question on using the Collect2qBlocks() and ConsolidateBlocks() optimizations

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'd like to run the optimizations from Qiskit's level 3 transpiler pass on some example programs for benchmarking, but when I try to include the Collect2qBlocks() and ConsolidateBlocks() passes I get an error. The code below is based on the example [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/transpiler/preset_passmanagers/level3.py).

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import Unroller, Optimize1qGates, CommutativeCancellation, CXCancellation, Depth, FixedPoint, Collect2qBlocks, ConsolidateBlocks

circ = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file("example.qasm")

basis_gates = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx']
_unroll = Unroller(basis_gates)
_depth_check = [Depth(), FixedPoint('depth')]
def _opt_control(property_set):
    return not property_set['depth_fixed_point']
_opt = [Collect2qBlocks(), ConsolidateBlocks(),
        Unroller(basis_gates),  # unroll unitaries
        Optimize1qGates(), CommutativeCancellation()]
pm = PassManager()
pm.append(_unroll)
pm.append(_depth_check + _opt, do_while=_opt_control)
circ = pm.run(circ)
print(circ.count_ops())
```

This seems to run fine if I exclude the Collect2qBlocks() and ConsolidateBlocks() passes, but when I include them I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_qiskit.py", line 19, in <module>
    circ = pm.run(circ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py", line 146, in run
    dag = self._do_pass(pass_, dag, passset.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py", line 183, in _do_pass
    pass_.run(FencedDAGCircuit(dag))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passes/collect_2q_blocks.py", line 59, in run
    these_qubits = sorted(nd.qargs)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'QuantumRegister' and 'QuantumRegister'
```

Am I invoking the methods incorrectly? I have the most recent version of Qiskit available on pip. Please let me know if you have any advice, thanks.

Comment: What version of qiskit are you running? I know you said you have the most recent verison, but looking at this line in the stacktrace `these_qubits = sorted(nd.qargs)`, this looks like it is from an older version of qiskit. When I look at the code in this file for the newest release, it says `these_qubits = set(nd.qargs)`. The newest release version of qiskit is 0.12.0. Granted, I tried your code in v0.12.0 with my own basic circuit and it worked. Maybe there is something happening with how the circuit is constructed?

Comment: Apparently I had version 0.10.5. To get 0.12.0, I needed to 'pip uninstall' qiskit and then 'pip install' it again. My code works now, thanks!

Comment: Hi @KeshaH. ! In order to make the answer more visible, would you mind writing a real answer (not a comment) and accepting it? Thank you, and happy to see that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question, as per the comments above. The solution was installing the latest version of qiskit. To get 0.12.0, I needed to 'pip uninstall' qiskit and then 'pip install' it again.